# Why the mybatis's MetaObject Class not support the path like "[0]"?

Tags: mybatis

I'm reading the mybatis code,than I found that MetaObject is a very important class.
We use it to access the property(even the nested property) of Object.
If we have a Object like this:

```
{
  "a": {
      "b":[1,2,3]
  }
}
```

When we want to get the value of b[0];
And we always use the form like this:

`metaObject.getValue("a.b[0]");`

Everything is fine.

But,If I have a collection like this:

```
// create a single element list: [1]
MetaObject mo = MetaObject.forObject(
      new ArrayList<String>() {{add("1");}},
      new DefaultObjectFactory(),
      new DefaultObjectWrapperFactory(),
      new DefaultReflectorFactory()
);

// If I want get the element of collection.
// It will cause an error.
System.out.println(metaObject1.getValue("[0]"));

// Because the CollectionWrapper is not implements the 'get' method.
// the code is following:
public Object get(PropertyTokenizer prop) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

So,I don't understand why we don't support this way to find a element of collection like "[0]".

Now we just support access the collection's element form a outer object like "b[0]",and the b is a property of a object.

Has anybody know that?

Comment: `java.util.Collection` does not guarantee order and does not allow access by index. `java.util.List` does. Usually, developers need to use all items in a collection, so `<foreach>` works fine. If you need only one item of a list for some reason, you can still use `<foreach>` with `begin` and/or `end` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The core reason is 'java.util.Collection does not guarantee order and does not allow access by index.'.

When we access the collection property of bean or map it will be cast to Array or List.

If the collection property by accessed is not Array or List, we will throw a ReflectionException.

So we needn't worry about the order of collection.

The core code as following:

```java
protected Object getCollectionValue(PropertyTokenizer prop, Object collection) {
    if (collection instanceof Map) {
      return ((Map) collection).get(prop.getIndex());
    } else {
      int i = Integer.parseInt(prop.getIndex());
      if (collection instanceof List) {
        return ((List) collection).get(i);
      } else if (collection instanceof Object[]) {
        return ((Object[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof char[]) {
        return ((char[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof boolean[]) {
        return ((boolean[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof byte[]) {
        return ((byte[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof double[]) {
        return ((double[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof float[]) {
        return ((float[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof int[]) {
        return ((int[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof long[]) {
        return ((long[]) collection)[i];
      } else if (collection instanceof short[]) {
        return ((short[]) collection)[i];
      } else {
        throw new ReflectionException("The '" + prop.getName() + "' property of " + collection + " is not a List or Array.");
      }
    }
  }
```